Как изменить inline кнопки при нажатии telebot
Делаю бота для игры "Супер крестики нолики". По правилам игры первым ходом игрок (крестик) выбирает сначала поле на которое он будет ходить, а потом клетку в этом поле.
Так вот, у меня сначала выводится поле из inline кнопок 3 на 3, в которых игрок выбирает поле на которое он будет ходить, а после это сообщение должно изменяться на такое же поле из кнопок 3 на 3, но при этом должно выводиться уже другое поле (grid_one, grid_two и т.д. до nine).
Вопрос: Как изменить в сообщении при нажатии определённой кнопки поле из кнопок?
Код:
Функции:
def game_grid(values_dict, all_moves_set):
    game_value = packaging_values(values_dict, all_moves_set)

    grid = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    grid.row_width = 3
    for i in range(1, 10, 3):
        grid.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 0),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 0}-{game_value}'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 1),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 1}-{game_value}'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 2),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 2}-{game_value}'))
    return grid

def grid_one(values_dict, all_moves_set):
    game_value = packaging_values(values_dict, all_moves_set)
    grid_one = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    for i in range(1, 10, 3):
        grid_one.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 0),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 0}-{game_value}'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 1),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 1}-{game_value}'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 2),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 2}-{game_value}'))
    return grid_one
def grid_two(values_dict, all_moves_set):
    game_value = packaging_values(values_dict, all_moves_set)
    grid_two = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    for i in range(1, 10, 3):
        grid_two.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 0),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 0}-{game_value}'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 1),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 1}-{game_value}'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 2),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 2}-{game_value}'))
    return grid_two
def grid_three(values_dict, all_moves_set):
    game_value = packaging_values(values_dict, all_moves_set)
    grid_three = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    for i in range(1, 10, 3):
        grid_three.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 0),
                                          callback_data=f'1-{i + 0}-{game_value}'),
                     InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 1),
                                          callback_data=f'1-{i + 1}-{game_value}'),
                     InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 2),
                                          callback_data=f'1-{i + 2}-{game_value}'))
    return grid_three
def grid_four(values_dict, all_moves_set):
    game_value = packaging_values(values_dict, all_moves_set)
    grid_four = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    for i in range(1, 10, 3):
        grid_four.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 0),
                                          callback_data=f'1-{i + 0}-{game_value}'),
                     InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 1),
                                          callback_data=f'1-{i + 1}-{game_value}'),
                     InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 2),
                                          callback_data=f'1-{i + 2}-{game_value}'))
    return grid_four
def grid_five(values_dict, all_moves_set):
    game_value = packaging_values(values_dict, all_moves_set)
    grid_five = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    for i in range(1, 10, 3):
        grid_five.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 0),
                                          callback_data=f'1-{i + 0}-{game_value}'),
                     InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 1),
                                          callback_data=f'1-{i + 1}-{game_value}'),
                     InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 2),
                                          callback_data=f'1-{i + 2}-{game_value}'))
    return grid_five
def grid_six(values_dict, all_moves_set):
    game_value = packaging_values(values_dict, all_moves_set)
    grid_six = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    for i in range(1, 10, 3):
        grid_six.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 0),
                                          callback_data=f'1-{i + 0}-{game_value}'),
                     InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 1),
                                          callback_data=f'1-{i + 1}-{game_value}'),
                     InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 2),
                                          callback_data=f'1-{i + 2}-{game_value}'))
    return grid_six
def grid_seven(values_dict, all_moves_set):
    game_value = packaging_values(values_dict, all_moves_set)
    grid_seven = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    for i in range(1, 10, 3):
        grid_seven.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 0),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 0}-{game_value}'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 1),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 1}-{game_value}'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 2),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 2}-{game_value}'))
    return grid_seven
def grid_eight(values_dict, all_moves_set):
    game_value = packaging_values(values_dict, all_moves_set)
    grid_eight = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    for i in range(1, 10, 3):
        grid_eight.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 0),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 0}-{game_value}'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 1),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 1}-{game_value}'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 2),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 2}-{game_value}'))
    return grid_eight
def grid_nine(values_dict, all_moves_set):
    game_value = packaging_values(values_dict, all_moves_set)
    grid_nine = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    for i in range(1, 10, 3):
        grid_nine.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 0),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 0}-{game_value}'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 1),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 1}-{game_value}'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 2),
                                      callback_data=f'1-{i + 2}-{game_value}'))
    return grid_nine


def empty_game_grid(values_dict):
    grid = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    grid.row_width = 3
    for i in range(1, 10, 3):
        grid.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 0),
                                      callback_data=f'none'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 1),
                                      callback_data=f'none'),
                 InlineKeyboardButton(text=show_value(values_dict, i + 2),
                                      callback_data=f'none'))
    return grid


def show_value(values_dict, index):
    index = str(index)
    value = str(values_dict[index])
    return value


def packaging_values(values_dict, all_moves_set):
    value_str = ''
    for i in values_dict:
        value_str += str(values_dict[i])
    value_str += '-'
    for i in all_moves_set:
        value_str += str(i)
    return value_str


def unpacking_values(value_str):
    data = value_str.split('-')
    move = data[1]
    dict_str = data[2]
    set_str = data[3]

    values_dict = {'1': ' ', '2': ' ', '3': ' ',
                   '4': ' ', '5': ' ', '6': ' ',
                   '7': ' ', '8': ' ', '9': ' '}
    for i in range(1, 10):
        values_dict[str(i)] = dict_str[i - 1]

    all_moves_set = set(set_str)
    return move, values_dict, all_moves_set


def check_win(values_dict):
    check_data = [
        [values_dict['1'], values_dict['2'], values_dict['3']],
        [values_dict['4'], values_dict['5'], values_dict['6']],
        [values_dict['7'], values_dict['8'], values_dict['9']],
        [values_dict['1'], values_dict['4'], values_dict['7']],
        [values_dict['2'], values_dict['5'], values_dict['8']],
        [values_dict['3'], values_dict['6'], values_dict['9']],
        [values_dict['1'], values_dict['5'], values_dict['9']],
        [values_dict['3'], values_dict['5'], values_dict['7']]
    ]
    for i in check_data:
        if i[0] == i[1] == i[2] == '❌':
            return True, 'Вы победили'

        if i[0] == i[1] == i[2] == '⭕':
            return True, 'Вы проиграли'

    return False, 'none'


def check_win_small(values_dict):
    check_data = [
        [values_dict['1'], values_dict['2'], values_dict['3']],
        [values_dict['4'], values_dict['5'], values_dict['6']],
        [values_dict['7'], values_dict['8'], values_dict['9']],
        [values_dict['1'], values_dict['4'], values_dict['7']],
        [values_dict['2'], values_dict['5'], values_dict['8']],
        [values_dict['3'], values_dict['6'], values_dict['9']],
        [values_dict['1'], values_dict['5'], values_dict['9']],
        [values_dict['3'], values_dict['5'], values_dict['7']]
    ]
    for i in check_data:
        if i[0] == i[1] == i[2] == '❌':
            values_dict_main = {'1': ' ', '2': ' ', '3': ' ', '4': ' ', '5': ' ', '6': ' ', '7': ' ', '8': ' ', '9': ' '}
            return values_dict_main


        if i[0] == i[1] == i[2] == '⭕':
            values_dict_main = {'1': ' ', '2': ' ', '3': ' ', '4': ' ', '5': ' ', '6': ' ', '7': ' ', '8': ' ', '9': ' '}
            return values_dict_main


    return False, 'none'


message_handler:
        elif message.text == 'Игра с ботом':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
            stop_playbot = types.KeyboardButton('Закончить игру')
            markup.add(stop_playbot)
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Игра с ботом'.format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup, parse_mode="html")
            all_moves_set = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}

            values_dict = {'1': ' ', '2': ' ', '3': ' ',
                           '4': ' ', '5': ' ', '6': ' ',
                           '7': ' ', '8': ' ', '9': ' '}
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text="Игра началась",
                             reply_markup=game_grid(values_dict, all_moves_set))

callback:
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_data(call):
    if call.data[0] == '1':

        move, values_dict, all_moves_set = unpacking_values(call.data)

        if move in all_moves_set:
            if move == 1:
                bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.from_user.id, text="Выберите клетку",
                                              reply_markup=grid_one(values_dict, all_moves_set))
            if move == 1:
                bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.from_user.id, text="Выберите клетку",
                                              reply_markup=grid_two(values_dict, all_moves_set))
            if move == 1:
                bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.from_user.id, text="Выберите клетку",
                                              reply_markup=grid_three(values_dict, all_moves_set))
            if move == 1:
                bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.from_user.id, text="Выберите клетку",
                                              reply_markup=grid_four(values_dict, all_moves_set))
            if move == 1:
                bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.from_user.id, text="Выберите клетку",
                                              reply_markup=grid_five(values_dict, all_moves_set))
            if move == 1:
                bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.from_user.id, text="Выберите клетку",
                                              reply_markup=grid_six(values_dict, all_moves_set))
            if move == 1:
                bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.from_user.id, text="Выберите клетку",
                                              reply_markup=grid_seven(values_dict, all_moves_set))
            if move == 1:
                bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.from_user.id, text="Выберите клетку",
                                              reply_markup=grid_eight(values_dict, all_moves_set))
            if move == 1:
                bot.edit_message_reply_markup(call.message.from_user.id, text="Выберите клетку",
                                              reply_markup=grid_nine(values_dict, all_moves_set))

            values_dict[move] = '❌'
            all_moves_set.remove(move)


Вопросы которые не стоит задавать => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (Поиск ошибок в коде. Прежде чем спрашивать «почему у меня не работает вот этот (простыня из тысячи строк) код?» постарайтесь сами локализовать проблему, выделить минимальный фрагмент кода, на котором, как вы считаете возникает проблема) как задать хороший вопрос => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
